# Vue js Vuex TypeError: context.dispatch(...) is not a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, setinterval

I have stopwatch function that can run the stopwatch like below :

**Stopwatch.vue**

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      time: "00:00.000",
      timeBegan: null,
      timeStopped: null,
      stoppedDuration: 0,
      started: null,
      running: false,
    };
  }
  methods: {
    start() {
      if (this.running) return;

      if (this.timeBegan === null) {
        this.timeBegan = new Date();
      }

      if (this.timeStopped !== null) {
        this.stoppedDuration += new Date() - this.timeStopped;
      }

      this.started = setInterval(this.clockRunning, 10);
      this.running = true;
    },
    clockRunning() {
      let currentTime = new Date();
      let timeElapsed = new Date(
        currentTime - this.timeBegan - this.stoppedDuration
      );
      let min = timeElapsed.getUTCMinutes();
      let sec = timeElapsed.getUTCSeconds();
      let ms = timeElapsed.getUTCMilliseconds();

      this.time =
        this.zeroPrefix(min, 2) +
        ":" +
        this.zeroPrefix(sec, 2) +
        "." +
        this.zeroPrefix(ms, 3);
    },
    zeroPrefix(num, digit) {
      let zero = "";
      for (let i = 0; i < digit; i++) {
        zero += "0";
      }
      return (zero + num).slice(-digit);
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.start();
  }
};
</script>
```

With the above function the stopwatch works well, but I want to move the function of the stopwatch using vuex so that it can make it easier for me to call the stopwatch function from any component.

**index.js** <-- In Vuex/store/stopwatch

```
export default {
  state: {
        time: "00:00.000",
        timeBegan: null,
        timeStopped: null,
        stoppedDuration: 0,
        started: null,
        running: false,
  },
    actions: {
    start(context) {
      if (context.state.running) return;
      if (context.state.timeBegan === null) {
        context.state.timeBegan = new Date();
      }

      if (context.state.timeStopped !== null) {
        context.state.stoppedDuration += new Date() - context.state.timeStopped;
            }
      context.state.started = setInterval(context.dispatch('clockRunning'), 10);
      context.state.running = true;
    },
    clockRunning(context) {
      let currentTime = new Date();
      let timeElapsed = new Date(
        currentTime - context.state.timeBegan - context.state.stoppedDuration
      );
      let min = timeElapsed.getUTCMinutes();
      let sec = timeElapsed.getUTCSeconds();
      let ms = timeElapsed.getUTCMilliseconds();

      context.state.time =
        context.dispatch('zeroPrefix')(min, 2) +
        ":" +
        context.dispatch('zeroPrefix')(sec, 2) +
        "." +
        context.dispatch('zeroPrefix')(ms, 3);
    },
    zeroPrefix(num, digit) {
      let zero = "";
      for (let i = 0; i < digit; i++) {
        zero += "0";
      }
      return (zero + num).slice(-digit);
    }
    },
  mutations: {},
  getters: {}
}
```

If I run the code above, I get an error :

[image]

I think the error occurs in the following line :

```
context.state.started = setInterval(context.dispatch('clockRunning'), 10);
```

But I didn't find any error in the line above.

This is the same line that works before move to vuex :

```
this.started = setInterval(this.clockRunning, 10);
```

How to solve the error above?

**Update** :

I made a demo code on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-js-vuex-typeerror-context-dispatch-is-not-a-function-b6vvy?file=/src/store/StopwatchQuestion/index.js)

I've tried changing it as @Estus Flask suggested but the error still appears,
I tried to change like the code below :

```
setInterval(() => context.dispatch('clockRunning'), 10)
```

But displays an error page that continues to grow every second until it becomes hundreds in a short time, with the appearance of the error makes my PC slow down and consumes all CPU performance to 100%.

Error appears as shown below :

[image: a]

Can anyone help to solve this error?

Comment: would it be store.dispatch('clockRunning') ?https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html#composing-actions

Comment: @Cameron, to access dispatch in actions i use `context` if i use `store` there will be error `store is not defined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put a stopper when the time reached 90 secs = 1min 30sec, but you can remove that. Just call a commit on 'stop'.

```
 export default {
  state: {
    time: "00:00.000",
    timeStarted: null,
    timeBegan: null,
    timeStopped: null,
    stoppedDuration: 0,
    started: null,
    running: false,
    maxSeconds: 90,
    temp:{
      min: "0",
      sec: "0",
      ms: "0",
      secondsPassed: 0
    }
  },
  actions: {
    start({state, commit, dispatch}) {
      if (state.running) return;
      if (state.timeBegan === null) {
        state.timeBegan = new Date();
      }

      if (state.timeStopped !== null) {
        state.stoppedDuration += new Date() - state.timeStopped;
      }

      commit("start", {
        callback:()=>{
          dispatch("stopIfReachedMaximumSeconds");
          dispatch("clockRunning");
        }
      });
    },
    async clockRunning({state, commit, dispatch}) {
      let currentTime = new Date();
      let timeElapsed = new Date(
        currentTime - state.timeBegan - state.stoppedDuration
      );
      let min = timeElapsed.getUTCMinutes();
      let sec = timeElapsed.getUTCSeconds();
      let ms = timeElapsed.getUTCMilliseconds();

      commit("newTemp", {
        key: 'secondsPassed',
        value: parseInt(Math.abs((state.timeStarted - new Date() )/ 1000))
      });

      if (state.running) {
        await dispatch("zeroPrefix",{num: min, digit:2}).then(zeroPrefixResponse => {
          commit("newTemp", {
            key: 'min',
            value: zeroPrefixResponse
          })
        });
  
        await dispatch("zeroPrefix",{num: sec, digit:2}).then(zeroPrefixResponse => {
          commit("newTemp", {
            key: 'sec',
            value: zeroPrefixResponse
          })
        });
  
        await dispatch("zeroPrefix",{num: ms, digit:3}).then(zeroPrefixResponse => {
          commit("newTemp", {
            key: 'ms',
            value: zeroPrefixResponse
          })
        });
        state.time = state.temp.min + ":" + state.temp.sec + "." + state.temp.ms;
      }
    },
    zeroPrefix(context, payload) {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        let zero = "";
        for (let i = 0; i < payload.digit; i++) {
          zero += "0";
        }
        resolve((zero + payload.num).slice(-payload.digit));
      });
    },

    stopIfReachedMaximumSeconds({state, commit}){
      if(state.temp.secondsPassed >= state.maxSeconds){
        console.log("REACHED MAXIMUM SECONDS");
        commit("stop");
      }
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    newTemp(state, payload){
      state.temp[payload.key] = payload.value;
    },
    addSecondPassed(state, second){
      state.temp.secondsPassed += second;
    },
    resetSecondPassed(state){
      state.temp.secondsPassed = 0;
    },
    start(state, payload){
      state.timeStarted = new Date();
      state.started = setInterval(()=>{
        payload.callback();
      }, 10);
      state.running = true;
    },
    stop(state){
      clearInterval(state.started);
      state.timeStarted = null;
      state.started = null;
      state.running = false;
      state.temp.secondsPassed = 0;
    }
  },
  getters: {}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The error means what it says, `context.dispatch('clockRunning')` expression is a promise while it's supposed to be a function, because the first argument of `setInterval` should be a function.

The first argument of `setInterval` should be a function. In case the intention is to dispatch an action on time interval, it should be:

```
setInterval(() => context.dispatch('clockRunning'), 10)
```

`dispatch` returns a promise, not a function. Action parameters should be passed as `dispatch` arguments:

```
context.dispatch('zeroPrefix', min, 2)
```

It's incorrect to use the result of `zeroPrefix` action in an expression. An action acts  on the store and is supposed to returns a promise of asynchronous operation, not result. The result needs to be written and read from the state. In this case `zeroPrefix` doesn't operate on the state and shouldn't be a part of the store at all, it has be extracted to helper function.

Comment: I've tried changing it as you suggested but the error still appears : `Uncaught TypeError: context.dispatch(...) is not a function`

Comment: I updated the posts. There are actually several mistakes.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far but i still get error when applying your suggested code. I updated my question with demo code on codesandbox to make it easier to solve this problem. I hope you can help me to solve this problem completely.

Comment: codesandbox doesn't contain fixed code. Use setInterval with much bigger delay if you have performance problems